# Remove rows from a dataframe based on a value in one column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (imported from a csv file) as follows

```
moose     loose     hoose
   2        3         8
   1        3         4
   5        4         2
   10       1         4
```

The R code should generate a mean column and then I would like to remove all rows where the value of the mean is <4 so that I end up with:

```
 moose     loose     hoose     mean 
   2        3         8        4.3
   1        3         4        2.6
   5        4         2        3.6
   10       1         4         5
```

which should then end up as:

```
  moose     loose     hoose    mean 
    2        3         8       4.3
    10       1         4        5
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

```
 dat2 <- subset(transform(dat1, Mean=round(rowMeans(dat1),1)), Mean >=4)
 dat2
  # moose loose hoose Mean
 #1     2     3     8  4.3
 #4    10     1     4  5.0
```

Using `data.table`

```
 setDT(dat1)[, Mean:=rowMeans(.SD)][Mean>=4]
 #  moose loose hoose     Mean
 #1:     2     3     8 4.333333
 #2:    10     1     4 5.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your data is called `d`. Then you run:

```
d$mean <- rowMeans(d)  ## create a new column with the mean of each row
d <- d[d$mean >= 4, ]  ## filter the data using this column in the condition
```

I suggest you read about creating variables in a `data.frame`, and filtering data. These are very common operations that you can use in many many contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `within`, which allows you to assign/remove columns and then returns the transformed data.  Start with `df`,

```
> df
#  moose loose hoose
#1     2     3     8
#2     1     3     4
#3     5     4     2
#4    10     1     4

> within(d <- df[rowMeans(df) > 4, ], { means <- round(rowMeans(d), 1) })
#  moose loose hoose means
#1     2     3     8   4.3
#4    10     1     4   5.0
```

Comment: Because I wanted the mean of three specific columns I used the following:df$Means <- rowMeans(df[,c(15:17)]) 
within(d <- df[df$Means>100,], { means <- round(df$Means(d), 1) })
View(d) but I get an error which says "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function"

Comment: `within(d <- df[rowMeans(df)>100, 15:17], { mean <- rowMeans(d) })`

Comment: Thanks Richard, although I still get Error in rowMeans(df) : 'x' must be numeric